# Add padding to sides of text in a button

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, constraints, xcode-storyboard

Using `Xcode's storyboard`, how can I add padding to the left and right of a `UIButton's` text? I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Here is my button:

[image]

I want the button to "hug" the text and then give padding of `32px` on the left and right sides of the button.

But when I try to add a `Title Inset`, it just squeezes the text to a point where it's almost not showing:

[image]

So how do I adjust the button's padding properly?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure following things are done for the Button in storyboard.

1. Update `Content insets` value for Left and Right as `32px` in `Size
   Inspector` in storyboard.
2. Also, ensure `Content Compression Resistance priority` -
   `Horizontal` value is high (751) for safer side.
3. Remove if you have any width constraint for Button, if possible.
4. Do not update Title insets. It will not work as you expected.

[image]

I have tested this. It's working for me.